# Must the name of an ldap group be unique?

Tags: openldap, groups

As we are setting up an openldap with multiple locations.
Must the names of the groups be unique? For example the vpn , adm, sudo group will be in NL but also in BE.
What is best practice? Could the same group names give any issues with connecting applications?

```
ou=NL,dc=company,dc=com
-ou=USERS
-ou=GROUPS
cn=sudo
cn=adm
cn=vpn
-ou=ROLES

ou=BE,dc=company,dc=com
-ou=USERS
-ou=GROUPS
cn=sudo
cn=adm
cn=vpn
-ou=ROLES
```

Kr,

Joeri

Answer (score 1):

Must be unique within the object's location (other siblings).

"An entry's relative distinguished name must be unique among all immediate subordinates of the entry's immediate superior (i.e., all siblings)."

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4512#page-8

Comment: Can you explain the definition of siblings within the openldap structure? See picture: http://i.imgur.com/BmZsUwk.png Short explenation: We are having an issue with the SSSD daemon. Apparently it can distinguish the difference between the admin group in belgium and the admin group in the netherlands. At user authentication the admin group is defined correctly being the first admin group. But after a while SSSD seems to use the last admin group that has been found in the openldap structure. Offcourse, the authenticated user does not belong to the last admin group and therefore lose admin rights

Comment: Siblings == peer objects in the same container. What you are describing sounds like an issue/limitation with the SSSD daemon, not the LDAP specification.